# Javascript - destructuring array of objects

Tags: javascript, destructuring

trying to get better grasp on destructuring.
If I have object like this:

```
const starWars = {
  count: 2,
  data: [
   {name: 'Luke Skywalker', films: ['Empire Strikes Back', 'The Force Awakens']}, 
   {name: 'Han Solo', films: ['New Hope', 'Return of the Jedi']}
  ]};
```

I can destructure data part like this:

```
const {data: allCharMovies} = starWars;
console.log(allCharMovies[1].name);
```

or I can try to do:

```
const { count, data: [{name: nameCh, films: movies}]} = starWars;
console.log(nameCh, movies[1]);
```

But but that only gives my movies for "Luke Skywalker" - how can I access "Han Solo" part if I do it the second way?

Comment: You can't. You are only extracting the first array element. Destructuring is not suitable for extracting a variable number of values, just like you usually don't declare variables dynamically.

Comment: You need to use `map` on the `data` array: `starWars.data.map(s => s.name)`. You can't do it just with destructuring .

Comment: So hmmm - I can extract array of objects into variable (allCharMovies) as long as I do not give that "receiving" array any structure. Otherwise if it has a structure - in second case - I can only point it at first element of array. OK - thanks - I am new to Javascript - just trying to understand basics.

Comment: *"I can only point it at first element of array"* No, you can extract any number of array elements. But you can't do that dynamically. For example this extracts the name of the first two elements: `const {data: [{name: name1}, {name: name2}]} = starWars;`. Either way, destructuring doesn't seem useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Felix - it is a class example. I literally started on JS yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another object destructuring in the array while destructuring `data`:

```js
const starWars = {
  count: 2,
  data: [
    { name: 'Luke Skywalker', films: ['Empire Strikes Back', 'The Force Awakens'] },
    { name: 'Han Solo', films: ['New Hope', 'Return of the Jedi'] }
  ]
};


const {
  count,
  data: [
    { name: nameCh, films: movies },
    { name: name2, films: movies2 }
  ]
} = starWars;

console.log(nameCh, movies[1]);
console.log(name2, movies2[1]);
```

Also, you can use the [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get all the movies except the first one:

```js
const starWars = {
  count: 2,
  data: [
    { name: 'Luke Skywalker', films: ['Empire Strikes Back', 'The Force Awakens'] },
    { name: 'Han Solo', films: ['New Hope', 'Return of the Jedi'] },
    { name: 'Chewbacca', films: ['New Hope', 'The Force Awakens', 'The Last Jedi'] }
  ]
};


const { count, data: [{ name: nameCh, films: movies }, ...otherMovies] } = starWars;

console.log(nameCh, movies[1]);
console.log(otherMovies[0].name, otherMovies[0].films[1]);
console.log(otherMovies[1].name, otherMovies[1].films[2]);
```

Comment: Yes of course - but what if I want Chewbacca and R2D2 too? (referring to first example).
And in second case I lose ability to reference 'nameCh' and 'movies' with the 'rest' part - I can only use the 'name' and 'films'.

Comment: Thanks Hao - I did - I just though that perhaps there is a way to combine the two.

Comment: Well, you can keep destructuring `otherMovies` like destructuring a normal array... but destructuring this deep is not recommended, which makes your code much harder to read.